# Splitting line by raster or vector attribute - Transect classification

Tags: qgis, line, split-by-attribute

I have a point, from this point I made 3 lines to the closest polygon with certain attibute.
Now I want to determine over what classification values ​​my line passes and the distances considering the order from the starting point to the end.

[image: Example, there could be more classes between the starting point and the end]

I was thinking about splitting my lines by the attributes of the classification, but I can't find the way.

Is there a way, QGIS complement or solution?

Comment: Are you aware of the ["Join attributes by location (summary)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary) ?

Comment: Would changing the raster into a vector dataset help? https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html?highlight=vectorize#polygonize-raster-to-vector